# Java: De dos arreglos relacionados (a[k] -> b[k]), seleccionar los elementos de valor máximo de un arreglo y mostrar los valores de ambos arreglos

Tags: java, array

Se me propuso el siguiente ejercicio: En un concurso de conocimiento se almacenan en un vector los nombres de N participantes y en otro vector las notas obtenidas (valores de 0 a 20), se pide mostrar el nombre del participante que obtuvo la mayor nota o ganadores en caso de múltiple empate.

Mi problema es que no se como mostrar a los ganadores en caso de múltiple empate.

Esto es lo que llevo de código:

```java
package Proyecto9;
       
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio5 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num, i=0, mayor=0;
        String nombres[]= new String[20];
        String nombresg[] = new String[20];
        String x=null,ng=null;
        int notas[]= new int[20];
        int ganadores[]= new int[20];
        boolean bd=false;
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de participantes: ");
        num = scan.nextInt();
       
        for (i=0;i<num;i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingresar nombre y nota #"+(i+1));
            nombres[i] = scan.next();
            notas[i] = scan.nextInt();
            while (notas[i]<=0 || notas[i]>20) {
                System.out.println("ERROR NOTA INVALIDA");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nuevamente la nota.");
                notas[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("La notas ingresadas son: ");
        for(i=0;i<num;i++){
            System.out.print(""+notas[i]+"\t");
        }
        
        for (i=0;i<num;i++){
            if(notas[i]>mayor){
                mayor=notas[i];
                x=nombres[i];
            } 
            if(mayor>=ganadores[i]){
                ganadores[i]=mayor;
                x=nombres[i];
            } 
        }

        if(bd==true){
            System.out.println("Los ganadores son: ");
            for(i=0;i<g;i++){
                System.out.print(""+nombresg[i]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El ganador es: "+x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usando las estructuras de datos que estás usando actualmente, tendría que buscarse por todo el array de notas y guardar el índice y el valor del ganador (del mayor). En el mismo ciclo que pinta las notas, por ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para la solución:

1. Encontrar la nota máxima de los participantes.
2. Iterar desde 0 hasta la longitud de tu arreglo y si el elemento i de tus calificaciones es igual a la nota máxima, imprimir el elemento i de tus nombres

**Nota:** Para encontrar la nota máxima he modificado tu variable [`int[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (que es un tipo de dato primitivo) a [`Integer[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) (que es una clase). Esto para facilitar el encontrar el valor más grande con [`Collections.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-). Pero se puede hacer con cualquier método en realidad.

Y quedaría algo así el código:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = {"Paco", "Olivia", "Marco", "Juana", "Pancho"};
        Integer[] scores = {10, 10, 9, 9, 7, 6};

        int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(scores));
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
            if(scores[i] == max)
                System.out.println(names[i] + " con puntuación de " + max);
        }
    }
}
```

Si no te animas todavía a usar las clases `Integer` ni `Collections` puedes obtener el máximo con un [foreach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) o un for-i y quedaría algo así tu código

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = {"Paco", "Olivia", "Marco", "Juana", "Pancho"};
        int[] scores = {10, 10, 9, 9, 7, 6};
        int max = scores[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; ++i) {
            if(scores[i] > max)
                max = scores[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
            if(scores[i] == max)
                System.out.println(names[i] + " con puntuación de " + max);
        }
    }
}
```

Con el [foreach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) se encontraría así el máximo

```java
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int score : scores) {
    if(score > max)
        max = score;
}
```

**Output** de la ejecución del programa:

```
Paco con puntuación de 10
Olivia con puntuación de 10
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, tu respuesta me ayudo, logre ejecutarlo de forma correcta.

Comment: Perfecta explicación. aunque lo mejor sería tener la clase Alumno en la que guardes tanto el nombre como la nota, y así ya están relacionados y no hay que recorrer dos arrays distintos. De esta manera, se aprovecharía la POO, que de eso va Java (cuando controles más el lenguaje, César)